# Get list changes in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am using CSOM library through Powershell to get a list of changes made to a list in Sharepoint Online. I am stuck while creating an object for the changecollection. Not sure how to get the data that comes from GetChanges. It doesn't return anything right now.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$scriptdir\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$context.RequestTimeOut = 1000 * 60 * 10;
$context.AuthenticationMode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientAuthenticationMode]::Default
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
$context.Credentials = $credentials
$web = $context.Web  
$site = $context.Site
$context.Load($web)  
$context.Load($site) 
$context.ExecuteQuery()
Set-Variable -Name "clientContext" -Value $context -Scope Global
Set-Variable -Name "rootSiteUrl" -Value $siteURL -Scope Global
Function Get-CQList {   
    $listName = "Tasks"
    $list = $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
    $cq = new-object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeQuery($true,$true)
    $col = new-object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeCollection  #returns "Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeCollection"
    $col = $list.GetChanges($cq)
    $clientContext.Load($col)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    $col.count
    foreach ($item in $col) {   
        # get data here from specific column name/row
    }   
}
```

Thank you for looking in to this!

**UPDATE:** 
I was able to get the output from GetChanges property. I had to add $clientContext.Load($col) after calling GetChanges. See the changes above. Now trying to figure out how to get the details for the changes made. The only output I get is this:

```
ListId             : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
WebId              : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ChangeToken        : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ChangeToken
ChangeType         : Add
SiteId             : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Time               : 11/4/2014 10:11:22 PM
Context            : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext
Tag                :
Path               :
ObjectVersion      :
ServerObjectIsNull : False
TypedObject        : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ChangeList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no need to create an instance of    [Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.changecollection%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [ClientContext.Load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171831(v=office.15).aspx) is missing for loading the collection of Change objects

**Example**

```
$listTitle = "Tasks"
$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
$qry = new-object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeQuery($true,$true)
$changes = $list.GetChanges($qry)
$context.Load($changes)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$changes | select ChangeType, Time
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim. I just noticed that the Load method was missing. And yes I removed the ChangeCollection instance. How do I get details about the change that happened? Like the specific item that changed? (Like the old values and the new values? or column names?)

Comment: For that purpose use Change.ChangeToken property that specifies a change token that identifies the changed object


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.change.changetoken(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Vadim, Do I have to change the query or have to create a new Change object? Can you give me an example?

Comment: hey Vadim, can you give me an example of the Change.ChangeToken? I am having a hard time figuring out how ChangeTokens work and getting the new/old values and other information I want out of the list. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Found your new question, sure, will post a more detailed example some later today ;)